# Modify the content of variable using sed (or something similar)

Tags: bash, sed

I wrote a  BASH file that features multiple embedded loops of the form

```
for P in {'0.10','0.20', [...] '0.90','1.00'}; do 
   for Q in {'0.10','0.20', [...] ,'0.90','1.00'}; do
    [...]
```

I use these variables both as parameters for a command line application, and to create file names directly in BASH. I would like to create duplicates, say `$P_REP=0_10` that replaces the dot by an underscore  without writting a explicit switch statement for every case, or some hardcoded equivalent. The (non-elegant way) I found to go about it is to

1. dump the content of `P,Q` to a temporary file.
2. replace the dot by an underscore using `sed 's/./_/ -i`.
3. read the file again and load its content to the new variable.

Hence, I was wondering if it is possible to run a sed like command directly on the content of a variable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do pattern substitution directly in bash:

```
P_REP=${P/./_}
Q_REP=${Q/./_}
```

From the bash(1) man page:

> #### Paramter Expansion
>
> **`${parameter/pattern/string}`**
>
> **Pattern  substitution.**   The  *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced with *string*.  If *pattern* begins with `/`, all matches of *pattern* are replaced with *string*.  Normally only the first match is replaced.  If *pattern* begins with `#`, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter.  If *pattern* begins  with `%`,  it  must  match  at  the  end of the expanded value of parameter.  If *string* is null, matches of *pattern* are deleted and the / following *pattern* may be omitted.  If parameter is `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied to each member  of  the  array  in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: Oh wow thank you. I'm not a bash expert and I did not know that there was such a thing as a man page for bash :-/. I will look there first next time!

Comment: @JGab Check out `{parameter#word}` and `${parameter%word}` as well, both under the same "Parameter Expansion" section of the man page. Bash can do a lot of cool things, but man oh man, its man page is **dense**.

Answer (score 15):

John Kugelman's answer is fine for your example, but if you need to process the content of a variable with the actual sed program (or some other arbitrary command), you can do it like this:

```
P_REP=$(sed 's/\./_/' <<< "$P")
```

Comment: This is the answer if you require captures in the substitution.

Comment: That is awesome.  I've been doing echo + pipe for nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

For loops you could use:

```
#!/bin/bash
P_REP=$(for P in '0.10' '0.20' '0.90' '1.00'; do echo ${P/./_} ; done)
Q_REP=$(for Q in '0.10' '0.20' '0.90' '1.00'; do echo ${Q/./_} ; done)

echo ${P_REP[@]}
echo ${Q_REP[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the exact problem you are mentionning, use John's proposition above.

I would however mention, in case you ever have to do something similar that can't be solved with bash's pattern substitution syntax, that you don't need to actually create temporary files to transform content with sed or similar commands. First, you can pipe a variable directly to a program as STDIN. Second, you may get the output of a command (oeither it's STDOUT, STDERR, or both) directly into a shell variable.

So in your example, you would have had:

```
for P in 0.10 0.20 [...] 0.90 1.00 ; do 
   for Q in 0.10 0.20 [...] 0.90 1.00 ; do
        P_REP=$( sed 's/\./_/g' <<< "$P" )
        Q_REP=$( sed 's/\./_/g' <<< "$Q" )
   done
done
```

Note also that the array syntax (that is `{ '0.10', '0.20', ...}`) is mostly specific to Bash and a very few Bash-followers. When it is easy to do so, you might prefer the more classical approach to for loops in shell, as I domonstrated above. Then your code will safetly execute in all posix-compliant shells.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated there is simple solution
You are changing ALL substrings ALL files in Folder / Catalog

```
ORG="orignal_string"
DES="destination_string"
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/'"${ORG}"'/'"${DES}"'/g' {} +
```