# How to substitute a particular string from a variable using sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am just trying to substitute a particular string from the value of a variable and  update that variable with the substituted string using sed

For eg.
`spath="$(which git)"`

Now i need to update the value of variable **spath** by having the string "git" replaced with string "c" after the which expression has evaluated .
Lets say if **which git** originally evaluates to **/usr/bin/git** ,then **spath** should be finally evaluate to **/usr/bin/c** after sed string substitution

Comment: To me it's not clear whether you want to replace the `git` within `spath="$(which git)"` or whether you want to replace it within the variable after the which has evaluated.  If it's the latter:  caveat emptor.

Comment: I don't need to replace the git within the spath="(which git)" , i need to replace it within the variable after the which has evaluated , sorry for framing it bit poorly , i will update the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551613/modify-the-content-of-variable-using-sed-or-something-similar ... dupe.

Comment: you can also use bash features instead of calling external cmds, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
spath="$(which git)"
spath=$(echo $spath | sed 's/git$/c/')
```

Comment: This will replace all occurrences of the string "git" with "c' -not just the last. A safer `sed` command would be `sed 's/git$/c/'`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result without using an external utility such as `sed` by using builtin `bash` string manipulation functionality.

```
$ spath="/usr/bin/git"
$ spath=${spath/%git/c}
$ echo $spath
/usr/bin/c
$
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this syntax with pipes?

Comment: Yes. Write a shell script which processes STDIN and outputs the resulting text to STDOUT.